# Why it is showing question mark when mouse over in react calender componant

Tags: reactjs

*[image: emphasized text]*[![ version i am using 3.7.0  I am using the react calendar component when  I bring the mouse over day as shown in the image its showing the question mark.I have not added additional style]][I am using the react calendar component when  I bring the mouse over day as shown in the image its showing the question mark.I have not added additional style][![

```html
 <Calendar
                        value={dateState}
                        minDate={new Date()}
                        //maxDate={new Date("12-31-2021")}

                        onChange={changeDate}
                        // onChange={date =>{ setSelectedDate(date);console.log("hi",selectedDate);showCalender(!show)}}
                      />
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKb9s.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKb9s.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide a bit of code ? How do you declare the calendar component, and what's the version of react-calendar you are using ?

Comment: @Guillaume I am using the version     "react-calendar": "^3.7.0",

Comment: Which browser cause this behaviour ? And do you use custom css or the default one : import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css';

Comment: @Guillaume Chrome browser we are using now.
And yes we are using the default css.

Comment: Seems like something is generating a `cursor: help;` style on days elements. If you can't manage to find what generate this you can maybe override the `react-calendar__month-view__weekdays__weekday`class with `cursor: default;`

Comment: @Guillaume can you please give simple example

Comment: Just create a .css with your custom style and override the class for the days div : react-calendar__month-view__weekdays__weekday. By inspecting with devtools did you find what create the `cursor: help`?